# Ruby - Print all methods in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I print all methods  for `network_sg` in the following code? I'm not sure what methods  are available.

Is it possible to print all methods  ? It has `Name` but not sure what other methods are available.

```
network_sg = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)

network_sg.list(rg).each do |network_sg|
    $evm.log('info', "azure network_sg test is: #{network_sg.name} ")
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keys". In Ruby, hashes have keys. Your code invokes a _method_ called `name`. If you want to know what other methods are available, try to print `network_sg.methods`. You could also try to figure out what kind of object you have (`network_sg.class`) and consult the documentation.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has not been maintained in many years and has open, unpatched security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what methods are available by using the `.methods` method. This will return an array of all the methods accessible to use (note that it won't show any private methods). I like to use it like `puts(network_sg.methods - Object.new.methods).inspect` to filter out all of the top level object methods and print out all of the non top level methods that are available.